# Почему статические переменные члены класса можно инициализировать внутри класса если они const и интегрального типа или перечисления?

Tags: c++

Почему статические переменные члены класса можно инициализировать  внутри класса если они const и интегрального типа или перечисления?

```
class Any {
private:
    static const double x = 1.0; //нельзя
};

class Any {
private:
    static const int a = 1; //можно
};
```

Почему `double` например нельзя?

в `с++11` добавили возможность инициализировать статические поля класса любого типа следующим образом:

```
class Any {
private:
    static constexpr double x = 1.0;
};
```

Как это работает? Не понимаю логику

Comment: В актуальной версии стандарта так можно инициализировать любые. А раньше были особые правила для целочисленных констант, чтобы упростить их использование в качестве размеров массивов, как параметров шаблонов и т.п.

Comment: @user7860670 с помощью синтаксиса в вопросе — всё ещё нельзя (https://godbolt.org/z/5GsddMv1r).

Comment: https://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#in-class

Comment: [C++ is Good for the Economy, It Creates Jobs!](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/)